# custom keyboard options do not work

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, 13.04

I have been trying to get the custom keyboard options to work. for example, to get the number 4 key to replace currency US$ by the INR(₹) sign. The option is there in the custom keyboard options in 13.04. But this does not seem to work. Any ideas how to get this working?

Please see the below screenshot.
[image]